# Should I pigtail a multi wire receptacle?

Tags: electrical

I replaced my old receptacle with a USB one.

[image: OLD]

The OLD had two wires to feed another receptacle.

The NEW one only had one set screw (But two back openings).

[image: new]

Directions only show a one wire diagram:

[image: instruc]

I installed both wires into the back and everything works fine.

My question is 1. Why only one screw? 2. Should I have pigtailed the hot and neutrals and run only one to the screw?

Comment: If you **had** a "Multi-Wire Branch Circuit" you could not use this receptacle on it, at least not without disconnecting half the circuit from this receptacle entirely. You don't appear to have that. You appear to have a branch circuit which this is in the middle of.

Comment: NEC 110.3(B) requires you obey the labeling and instructions.  Implied: you must *read* the labeling and instructions.  Does that shed any light on how to use that terminal type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, you should pigtail.** (Technically, you *could* use screws for one set of wires and backstab connections for the other set of wires, but for a bunch of reasons I don't recommend that.)

The question isn't "why only 1 screw on each side". The question really is "why do some receptacles have **two** screws on each side".

There are two reasons (naturally) for two screws:

- **Split Receptacle**

An ordinary receptacle (no USB, no GFCI) can be split so that the top and bottom are wired to different circuits or different parts of a circuit. This includes:

- a MultiWire Branch Circuit (MWBC), allowing for twice the power with only one additional wire (shared neutral, two hots, double breaker)
- two separate circuits (two hots, two neutrals)
- 1/2 switched (shared neutral, one regular hot, one switched hot)

In each of these cases, the metal bridge/tab connecting the two hot screws is removed. If the neutral is also separate then that metal bridge/tab is removed as well.

- **Line/Load**

This is usually found with GFCIs. Also with AFCI (but those are much less common). The incoming power goes to Line. Load is used to provide power to additional receptacles without having to install a separate GFCI for the other receptacles.

It happens to be that two screws on each side when you don't *need* the second screw makes for convenient daisy-chaining. But that's not *why* the screws exist.

A USB receptacle will not include GFCI (not enough space to get everything in there). It will also probably not have the option to split (it would get complicated - which part controls the USB?) Therefore, no second screw needed, so manufacturer saves 20 cents by not including the second screw.

Comment: This is a great answer, but what is the basis for the main statement" Yes, you should pigtail"? Pigtailing is not a code requirement AFAIK, so I believe you are giving your opinion here. Would you mind providing some context for your opinion? I am just a DIY guy, but I often install a receptacle the same way as shown in the OP, by using a single screw to secure two conductors. AFAIK this is code compliant and very frequently done.

Comment: In this *specific* situation: Single screw + backstab vs. pigtail, I say you **should** pigtail. I'll elaborate.

Comment: Pigtails are required on MWBCs, but this isn't one. OTOH, the new receptacle *appears to be* of the "screw and clamp" "backwire" persuasion (good, usable), not the "backstab, you'd be an idiot to use those" persuasion, at least from pictures, including the instructions (12-14 AWG, insert between wire clamp and terminal, tighten screw - NOT backstab 14Ga/15A only, no screw to tighten.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal Looking at the picture and the spec sheet, I was not 100% sure one way or the other. But pigtail is always safe and that's why I said *should*, not *must*.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start out by stating that your old outlet has the backstabs used and those have proven to be faulty, so stay away from them. Your new outlet has one screw that clamps two wires to the hot side and one screw that clamps two wires to the neutral side so pigtailing is not necessary. Personally, I would have pigtailed it because it easier to pigtail the installation, tuck the wire nuts and four wires back into the box and then connect the two wires from you pigtails to the outlet and then fit the outlet and two wires, three with ground, back into the box. It's much easier to stuff three wires and a large outlet into the box than 5 wires and a large outlet.